# How do I install the latest release of Drupal with Composer

Tags: composer

[Instructions on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies) for installing Drupal with composer provides the following example:

```
composer create-project drupal/drupal my_site_name 8.3.*@dev --no-dev
```

This provides me with the latest DEV version of Drupal. How do I get the lasted stable release?

Answer (score 2):

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev \
  YOURDIRNAME \
  --stability dev \
  --no-interaction
```

Comment: Edited for readability - note that \ continues the command in cli.

Comment: It is my understanding that there are two different templates for a Drupal 8 site -  
  
1- drupal/drupal (docroot is repo root)  
2- drupal-composer/drupal-project (docroot is subdir)  
  
I'm trying to install the latest version of Drupal using option #1 and am a little confused about the correct syntax for that.